# T3 template caching

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla3.0, browser-cache

I have a T3-framework based template on Joomla site installed. When I make some changes to template (for ex. Site Name/Slogan, some CSS color values with ThemeMagic, ...) and save, nothing updates in front-end. I have turned global site caching off, but nothing happend. CSS files code simply do not change, though if I will switch css to less, links to css files in page souce code change to less, but nothing more, the code is kept the same (old).

May be there is internal caching function in T3 I can turn off or may be I do something wrong saving changes to template?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this happens when the permissions for the folders are not set correctly. Navigate to the files and folders via your control panel and check that the permissions are set as:

1. Write-protect critical directories and files by changing directory permissions to 755.
2. File permissions to 644.